# framework to managing scrapy spiders

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a project in which I have implemented hundreds of scrapy spiders.
Now I collided with the following problems:

1. time to time websites changes their DOM/API - so spider stop working or not all info collected
2. websites became unavailable or moved to another domain - spider stop working.
3. Since there are a lot of spiders it not easy to monitor the status of each spider.

is there any framework that provides the ability to monitor scrapy spiders?

1. status of running spider(s)
2. show when spider(s) stop working etc.

I have looked into scrapinghub/zyte but not sure if it good for our purpose because we need something that can be running locally.

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapydweb](https://github.com/my8100/scrapydweb) is basically just like Scrapinghub but you run it locally.
It can alert you when spiders fail with email/slack if I remember correct. It's a bit less user-friendly than scrapinghub since you have to manage servers and so on. But overall I think it was a good platform when I used it.

Answer (score 0):

[Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) is a very handy platform for scheduling and monitoring.